# Locked landscape orientation on tablet + activity started when device in portrait = visible rotation on screen

Tags: android, rotation, orientation, tablet

I have an activity with locked orientation (setRequestedOrientation in OnCreate). It works fine on the phone and almost fine on the tablet.

The problem I have is with honeycomb tablets (motorola xoom and samsung), when activity is started when the user holds the device in portait mode, the activity is initially displayed in portait and then after a fraction of a second it rotates to landscape. Is there any way to stop it from happening?

Comment: Hi Maria! I have the same Problem, have you solved it? If yes, yould you tell me how? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to preset it in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" 
              ...
              android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
              />
```

Comment: I cannot do that becuase the orientation is depandant on the device (landscape for tablets and portait for most of the phones).